# gnuplot: error with axis label

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to use gnuplot and the eps latex terminal.

I created this image:
[image]
As you can see the x labels are all superposed. How I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.  You can rotate the xtics as maverik mentioned, or you can adjust the spacing by

```
set xtics 4e11
```

That will make a tic every 4e11 units, for example.

Gnuplot is not necessarily going to make an intelligent choice about how many tics there will be, such that they don't overlap.  If you have long-format tics (scientific notation like you have, or time data for instance) you often have to adjust the spacing manually.

Comment: And the choices it makes are especially bad for the various `latex` enabled terminals since `latex` is actually responsible for making the labels -- Gnuplot needs to guess at where `latex` is going to put them and act accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Try to rotate xtics. Like

```
set xtics nomirror rotate by -45 font ",8"
```